# Hoverintent - Whole menu (Div) to drop down?

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, slide, opencart

I'm trying to get a whole div to slide down upon hover.

To try and explain in more detail:

When you hover over the arrow underneath the logo...

[image]

I want it to slide down to reveal the menu, like so:

[image: Snap of menu]

I want the blue div, with the instrument icons, to down upon hovering over the little arrow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A bit more information would be useful with this. What have you done this far if anything?

Comment: I have added another image to try and explain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you get started:

```
$("#panelTriggerButton").mouseover(function(){
    if($("#panel").hasClass("activePanel")) {
        $("#panel").slideUp('slow').removeClass("activePanel");
        $(this).html("Open");
    } else {
        $("#panel").slideDown('slow').addClass("activePanel");
        $(this).html("Close");
    }
    return false;
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk5Qx/

Comment: I've just give this a go and it's almost exactly what I want! Although I want the menu div to slide as a whole from behind the top of the main navigation at the top, if that makes sense. As in, I don't want it to be hidden in css, I just want it to slide down on mouseover, and then slide back up on mouseout.